# Force Chrome autofill to actually fill fields

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autofill, web-extension

I am writing a web extension, and one task of it is to speed up the login process on a particular page by automatically submitting the credentials if the browser autofills them.

In Firefox I was able to simply use the `change` event to detect if text is entered, and by testing whether a `type` event also fired I can distinguish browser and user input.

In Chrome, however, I am unable to use these events, because they don't fire until the user clicks somewhere outside the input fields. In some places it is suggested to regularly check the value of the input fields, but that does not work either, they stay empty. I managed to use

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*:-webkit-autofill').length !== 0
```

to detect whether the browser autofilled the input fields. However, when I then click the submit button from JS, the login fails, because the exposed value of the input fields is still an empty string. I tried clicking onto the background or focusing the submit button from JS, but Chrome does still not fill the input fields if the click wasn't initiated by the user.

So my question is: is there a way to force Chrome to properly fill the input fields, such that the value can be read from JavaScript?

Comment: Use `input` event instead of `change`.

Comment: I already tested many events and none fire: `change`, `input`, `type`, `keyup`, `blur`

Comment: The `input` event fires when the user types without the need to click elsewhere. There's no event for autofilling. There's also no way to read the autofiled values in order to prevent private data exfiltration by the sites.

Comment: I don't understand why the credentials shouldn't be fully entered immediately, as they will be exposed to JS later on anyways (after the user clicked somewhere).

My only guess why this would be useful was if the user didn't want to use the autofilled credentials. However, I tried changing the autofilled value (clicking on it or pressing delete), but that always resulted in the value being submitted. Thus this is absolutely no protection against data exfilitration.

Comment: User gesture requirement is the common gating mechanism of the web, so apparently it's also used here.

Comment: Yes, I see, but unfortunately it is completely useless in Chrome because the implementation is stupid.